# I am having an issue redrawing some circles onto my html canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am using a basic html canvas to create a simple game using javascript, but I am having an issue while trying to redraw my window. I have created a redraw_window function that I call whenever i want a new frame to show on the screen, but when I try to call the redraw_window function from this location on line 151, it does not work. The screen does not update. Any ideas why?

````
const c = canvas.getContext("2d")

canvas.width =  innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

const random = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

class Light {
   constructor(pos,vel){
       this.pos = pos
       this.vel = vel
   }
   move(){
       if (this.pos == 0){
           this.vel = 1
       }
       if(this.pos == 9){
           this.vel = -1
       }
       this.pos += this.vel
   }
}
function is_not_in(val,list){
   for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
       if (list[i] == val){
           return false
       }
   }
   return true
}

function clear_window(){
   c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
 const date = Date.now();
 let currentDate = null;
 do {
   currentDate = Date.now();
 } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

function redraw_window(pos){
   c.font = "80px serif"
   //let board = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
   positions = [canvas.width/2-450,canvas.width/2-350,canvas.width/2-250,canvas.width/2-150,canvas.width/2-50,canvas.width/2+50,canvas.width/2+150,canvas.width/2+250,canvas.width/2+350,canvas.width/2+450,]
   //board[light.pos] = 0
   clear_window()
   c.fillStyle = "black"
   //c.fillText(board.toString(),canvas.width/2-c.measureText(board.toString()).width/2,canvas.height/2)
   //c.fillText("Troy likes big hairy black balls",canvas.width/2-c.measureText("Troy likes big hairy black balls").width/2,canvas.height/2+80)
   for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
       let radius = 20
       if (pos != i){
           c.beginPath()
           c.arc(positions[i],canvas.height/2,radius,0,Math.PI * 2,false)
           c.fillStyle = "black"
           c.fill()    
       }
       if (pos == i){
           c.beginPath()
           c.arc(positions[i],canvas.height/2,radius,0,Math.PI * 2,false)
           c.fillStyle = "green"
           c.fill()    
       }
   }
   
}


function choose(choices) {
 var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
 return choices[index];
}



function win_animation(){
       redraw_window(null)
       sleep(300)
       redraw_window(light.pos)
       sleep(300)
       redraw_window(null)
       sleep(300)
       redraw_window(light.pos)
   }

var light = new Light(random(0,9),choose([-1,1]))

function main(){
   var FPS = 60
   var SPEED = 0.5
   var COOLDOWN = FPS * 0.25
   var SCORE_TO_WIN = 5
   var right_player_points = 0
   var left_player_points = 0
   var frame = 0
   var right_player_cooldown = 0
   var left_player_cooldown = 0
   var keys_pressed = []
   var right_player_key = "ShiftRight"
   var left_player_key = "ShiftLeft"
   var right_player_cooldown = 0
   var left_player_cooldown = 0
   var playing = true

   


   //handles cooldown and keys pressed list
   window.addEventListener("keydown",(event)=>{
       if (event.code == right_player_key && is_not_in(right_player_key,keys_pressed)){
           if (right_player_cooldown == 0){
               right_player_cooldown = COOLDOWN
               keys_pressed.push(event.code)

           }
       }   
       if (event.code == left_player_key && is_not_in(left_player_key,keys_pressed)){
           if (left_player_cooldown == 0){
               left_player_cooldown = COOLDOWN
               keys_pressed.push(event.code)

           }
       }
   })

   //runs fps times per second
   var run = setInterval(run,1000 / FPS)
   function run(){
       frame += 1



       if (left_player_cooldown > 0){
           left_player_cooldown -= 1
       }
       if (right_player_cooldown > 0){
           right_player_cooldown -= 1
       }
       

       //runs SPEED times per second
       if (frame >= FPS * SPEED){
           frame = 0
           
           if (!is_not_in(right_player_key,keys_pressed) && light.pos == 9){
               right_player_points += 1
               **VVV THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING MY ISSUE VVV**
               redraw_window(null);
               alert("right player:" + right_player_points.toString())
               if (right_player_points >= SCORE_TO_WIN){
                   alert("right player Wins")
                   right_player_points = 0
                   left_player_points = 0
                   light = new Light(random(0,9),choose([-1,1]))
               }

           }


           if (!is_not_in(left_player_key,keys_pressed) && light.pos == 0){
               left_player_points += 1
               light = new Light(random(0,9),choose([-1,1]))
               alert("left player:" + left_player_points.toString())
               if (left_player_points >= SCORE_TO_WIN){
                   alert("left player wins")
                   left_player_points = 0
                   right_player_points = 0
               }
           }

           
           light.move()
           redraw_window(light.pos)
           keys_pressed = []   
           
           
       }
   }
}
main() ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I can see here is that you have a variable and a function both named `run`. The `setInterval` call is being overwritten with the function definition. I recommend you rename the variable `run` to `runInterval`.

Change

```
var run = setInterval(run, 1000 / FPS)
```

to

```
var runInterval = setInterval(run, 1000 / FPS)
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion however changing this did not solve my issue. When running my redraw_window function in line 151, the canvas does not update.

Comment: Have you put a `console.log` statement before that line to ensure it is reaching that line of code? Have you put a `console.log` statement inside the `redraw_window` function to ensure it is running the function?

Comment: Yes I have. the function seems to run fine, only the window is not being updated. it seems very strange to me.

Comment: I have tested this in CodePen and it seems to be updating the window fine. What is meant to happen that isn't?

Comment: It seems that the redraw_window function is only showing up after the complete if statement is finished and after the alert is closed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Well `alert` is a synchronous operation and will pause execution until it completes, ie. the user presses OK. I am still unsure what you mean by 'showing up'. What is the redraw_window function meant to do that isn't happening?